# SSL connection test

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I'm writing an application in JAVA, which checks an SSL connection per provided host.
Part of the test should be ciphers and protocol versions checks.

How can I preform connection with specific cipher or protocol version(SSL 3 or 2, TLS 1), to check if it is enabled by the server?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using linux... you could do a system call and use openssl to check the connection:
for example using this command:

```
openssl s_client -no_tls1 -no_ssl3 -connect www.google.com:443 
//this checks if ssl v2 is availabe
```

and then parse the output in your JAVA program.

Comment: It's an application for windows.